# Powershell Script running appropriately on one machine but not on the rest

Tags: powershell, debugging, testing, include, get-childitem

I am currently working with the script below and trying to get it to run on several machines.

I have ran it perfectly fine on 2 machines however when running on another 3 I am getting a lot of output paths to almost everything not even being called for by `-Include`.

Stomped since it works fine for 2 machines but not for the rest.

```
Get-ChildItem B:\, C:\, E:\, F:\, G:\, H:\, I:\, J:\, K:\, L:\, M:\, Q:\ -Force `
    -Include "*.pdf", "*.xls",".txt", ".html", "*.txt" -Recurse -EA Silentlycontinue |
    Foreach-Object { $_.Fullname } |
    Out-File "C:\LOGS\PATHFINDER$(Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss).txt" -Width 1024
```

Comment: Hi, is the PS version the same on all hosts ? Check the `$PSVersionTable` for instance.

Comment: One of the machines which it is working on is CLR Ver 5.0 and one which is not working is CLR Ver 2.0

Comment: I think you mean `PSVersion` but anyway, if you can afford it, you should update PowerShell on the V2 host (to match the version of the others). If you cannot, you will have to test the behavior of the `-Include` argument on V2 and adapt your script accordingly.

Comment: Sorry PS Version** Interesting on the other machine where the script worked it is PS Version 2.0

Comment: Just a point of order (because @sodawillow is 100% on point already), but you're doing a `-Recurse` in the code, but DON'T want to see all the other possible output paths?  I would recommend looking up what `-Recurse` does, since it's potentially going to dig deep into your folder hierarchies, regardless.

Comment: I want it to look deep and for it to output the paths for which the files are being found in. The issue is the script is simply outputting paths to everything and not just those where the certain files are being found.

Comment: @gravity, `-Include` only works when `-Recurse` is specified, so he has to do it like this.  

ElCaptian, if this code works, it will just output a ton of txt files with a YYYY-MM_dd format.  Is that what you want to do, each one will contain the full path to a file.  I'm having a hard time conceiving of how this could be useful.

Comment: Actually the generated Txt contains the path to each individual file found. The issue was that the path to everything was being generated inside the txt.